# overload operator [] linked list

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T>
int& listvector<T>::operator[](int n)
{   
    Node*p = new Node;
    p->data = NULL;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        p = p->next;
    }
    p->next = head;
    head = p;

    return head->data;
}
```

I am trying to overload a operator[] in my class listvector. This operator[] is used to  add the node which is NULL to the list(n is the place that return the value of the list). For example, when in main listV[4] = new int(10), means that NULL NULL NULL NULL 10 in the list. In my code, I don't know why I can not assign NULL to 0-3   only the first one is NULL.

Comment: There are quite a few problems in that short function. Including (but not limited to) the possibility of going of the end of the list and a memory leak and some [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when dereferencing invalid pointers.

Comment: ??????where is the problem

Comment: Lets begin with the invalid pointer issue: You have the pointer `p`, which is pointing to a single `Node` object that is totally *independent of any list*. Now, where does `p->next` point? If the constructor is doing its job then it should be a null pointer, otherwise it's a seemingly random and *indeterminate* pointer.

Comment: If i use Node*p = head;. I don't know if i can  put p->data = NULL in my for loop. If i put function still only run like what i want, but no error occur.

Comment: Then that `p->data = NULL` is probably *wrong*.

Comment: but i need to set they empty node as NULL

Comment: And regarding the going-of-the-end issue. What if the argument `n` is a value larger than the number of nodes in the list?

Comment: just add new node which is NULL in the list

Comment: A list should not have "empty" nodes. Besides, the symbolic constant `NULL` is a left-over from C and is used for null *pointers* not for non-existing values (such values doesn't exist in C++).

Comment: i assume the list is empty in the begining, so head = NULL at first

Comment: I know don t have empty node. I just want to set all the node which is less than n is NULL. In the example listV[4] have value 10, but 0-3 don t have ,so the data is NULL for listV[0],listV[1]...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, lets get a working function going.

The first problem is that your node structure seems to be *internal*, so you can't use the `operator[]` function to *add* new nodes. I deduce that because you return the *value* contained in a node, not the node itself. Using an index-operator to add nodes to a list really makes no sense anyway, since it requires you to create a possibly new list from nothing.

So lets concentrate on a *getter* version of the function, which gets the value of an existing node in position `n`. This is very simple:

```
// Function to get the data in element `n`
int operator[](size_t n) const  // Make function `const` since it will not modify the internal data
{
    // Start at the head of the list
    Node* current = head;

    // Loop as long as we don't go of the end of the list and `n` is larger than zero
    // Also decrement `n` after checking its value
    while (current != nullptr && n-- > 0)
    {
        // Make `current` point to the next node in the list
        current = current->next;
    }

    // If `current` is a null pointer, then we have gone of the end of the list, return some default value
    // Otherwise return the value of node we were looking for
    return (current == nullptr ? 0 : current->data);
}
```

<sub>[Note that I have followed your function return type, to return an `int` even though it should probably be `T`]</sub>

Comment: My list at the begining is empty, so i don t think that way is possible. At first head is equal to NULL

Comment: @Lou Then `current` will be a null pointer, the loop will not happen, and `0` be returned.

Comment: but while loop is current!=NULL, it at first is equal to NULL